# Convert hours, mins, secs String to hours

Tags: java, time, periodformatter

I want to convert a time in the below format into hours.

My input which is a time format could be anything like

```
1 hour 30 mins 20 secs 
2 hrs 10 mins 
45 mins
```

whereas my output will be:

```
1.505
2.167
0.75
```

These are the hours.

Currently I am doing it manually by parsing the input string `1 hour 30 mins 20 secs`, finding whether the word `hour/hours/hrs/hr` is present, then taking the preceding digits--the same for mins and secs. I use the formula to convert mins and secs to hours manually.

Is there any built-in provision that I can use in Java?

Comment: There is a thrird party library **JNLP** for natural language processing but that would be overkill.

Comment: Have you checked Joda-time? It has period parsing capabilities that include this possibility.

Comment: Using decimals to represent a span of time in hours is unwise. I suggest you look at the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard formats for durations, and look at the java.time class [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).  `java.time.Duration.parse( "PT1H30M20S" )`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way would be to parse it as [a `Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html), but you will need to change the format a bit first. Something like:

```
String adjusted = input.replaceAll("\\s+(hour|hr)[s]\\s+", "H");
//Do the same for minutes and seconds
//So adjusted looks like 1H30M20S
Duration d = Duration.parse("PT" + adjusted);

double result = d.toMillis() / 3_600_000d;
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `(hour|hr)` instead of `[hour|hr]`? The regex with `[]` doesn't match the whole string "hour" or "hr"

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what happens when you write code on a mobile without a compiler!

Answer (score 2):

Usually I wouldn't recommend [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (as it's being replaced by the new Java API's), but it's the only API I know with a good formatter/parser for periods.

You can use the `PeriodFormatterBuilder` class and use `appendSuffix` method to define the suffixes for singular and plural values for each field:

```
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

// method to parse the period
public void getPeriod(String input) {
    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            // hours (singular and plural suffixes)
            .appendHours().appendSuffix("hour", "hours")
            // minutes
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min", "mins")
            // seconds
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("sec", "secs")
            // create formatter
            .toFormatter();

    // remove spaces and change "hr" to "hour"
    Period p = formatter.parsePeriod(input.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("hr", "hour")); 

    double hours = p.getHours();
    hours += p.getMinutes() / 60d;
    hours += p.getSeconds() / 3600d;
    System.out.println(hours);
}

// tests
getPeriod("1 hour 30 mins 20 secs");
getPeriod("2 hrs 10 mins");
getPeriod("45 mins");
```

Output:

> 1.5055555555555555
>   2.1666666666666665
>   0.75

---

Another way of creating the `PeriodFormatter` is using `appendSuffix` with regular expressions. It's useful when you have lots of different options for the suffix (like `hour` and `hr` for the hours field):

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    // hours (all possible suffixes for singular and plural)
    .appendHours()
    .appendSuffix(
        // regular expressions for singular and plural
        new String[] { "^1$", ".*", "^1$", ".*" },
        // possible suffixes for singular and plural
        new String[] { " hour", " hours", " hr", " hrs" })
    // optional space (if there are more fields)
    .appendSeparatorIfFieldsBefore(" ")
    // minutes
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" min", " mins")
    // optional space (if there are more fields)
    .appendSeparatorIfFieldsBefore(" ")
    // seconds
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" sec", " secs")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
```

Note that I've also added `appendSeparatorIfFieldsBefore(" ")` to indicate that it has a space before the next field.

The good thing about this version is that you don't need to pre-process the input:

```
// no need to call replaceAll (take input just as it is)
Period p = formatter.parsePeriod(input);
```

The output is the same as above.

---

## Java 8 date-time API

As stated in [@assylian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44377716/7605325), you can use the `java.time.Duration` class:

```
public void getDuration(String input) {
    // replace hour/min/secs strings for H, M and S
    String adjusted = input.replaceAll("\\s*(hour|hr)s?\\s*", "H");
    adjusted = adjusted.replaceAll("\\s*mins?\\s*", "M");
    adjusted = adjusted.replaceAll("\\s*secs?\\s*", "S");
    Duration d = Duration.parse("PT" + adjusted);

    double hours = d.toMillis() / 3600000d;
    System.out.println(hours);
}

//tests
getDuration("1 hour 30 mins 20 secs");
getDuration("2 hrs 10 mins");
getDuration("45 mins");
```

The output is the same.

**PS:** if your Java version is <= 7, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). The class name and methods are the same, the only difference is the package name: `org.threeten.bp` instead of `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm doing like this :

```
private double convertToHours(String inputTime) {
    inputTime = " 1 hour 30 mins 20 secs";
    double hours = 0;
    List<String> timeList = Arrays.asList(inputTime.split(" "));
    ListIterator<String> iterator = timeList.listIterator();
    String time = null;
    String previous = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        int prevIndex = iterator.previousIndex();
        time = (String) iterator.next();

        if (!time.isEmpty() && time != null) {

            if (time.contains("hours") || time.contains("hrs") || time.contains("hr") || time.contains("hour")) {
                // time = time.substring(0, time.indexOf('h'));
                    previous = timeList.get(prevIndex);

                hours = hours + Double.parseDouble(previous.trim());
            }

            if (time.contains("mins") || time.contains("min") || time.contains("mns")) {
                //time = time.substring(0, time.indexOf('m'));
                previous = timeList.get(prevIndex);
                hours = hours + Double.parseDouble(previous) / 60;
            }

            if (time.contains("secs") || time.contains("sec") || time.contains("scs")) {
                //time = time.substring(0, time.indexOf('s'));
                previous = timeList.get(prevIndex);
                hours = hours + Double.parseDouble(previous) / 3600;
            }
        }
    }
    return hours;
}
```